# Modal-like or pop-in / out route transition using Ionic 5 animation API

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic5

I want use a transition like the present WhatAapp transition in Ionic 5, like this using the animation API in Ionic 5.

Example:

https://i.imgur.com/Zywb3HM.gif

```
import { createAnimation } from "@ionic/core";
import { getIonPageElement } from "./Helpers/helpers";
import { TransitionOptions } from "./types";

export const transitionAnimation = (
  _: HTMLElement,
  opts: TransitionOptions
) => {
  // Animation goes here
  return rootTransition;
};
```

My client requested it I think React Native have that out of the box.